# What does $_GET['_t'] signify

Tags: php

Is there some type of data that is passed as `_t`? I see this a lot in some code and cannot figure out what it signifies

Comment: in "some code" - what code do you see it in?

Comment: No, there is nothing special about `_t`.

Comment: "I see this a lot in some code" - what code?

Comment: Looks like a terrible array key to me.  Where have you seen this?

Comment: With all the weirdness of PHP, I don't think this is a particularly bad question for a beginner to ask if they are really seeing this in a lot of code, but that's the part I have doubts about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.  Just a regular key for the `$_GET[]` array.

Also, that `'_t'` could come from the http query string or from a form submitted as `GET`.  Might want to comb over your HTML for clues into its meaning.

Comment: cool. Thanks. I thought it was some kind of a standard representation

Comment: Personally I do in fact use "special" GET/POST keys, like `_redirect`. Guess what that does? ;) It's good to pick something unlikely if you are going to do that.

Comment: The almighty `'_t'` key take another 20 years of development knowledge to figure out its meaning.  Didn't know programming could be so zen :D

Answer (score 1):

That means that someone set a get variable `_t` as something, and you are getting the value of it.

Answer (score 0):

[`_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) is actually a predefined associative array of key-value pairs and its filled up by the HTTP GET request *dynamically*. If no parameters passed in the `GET` request towards your web server this array would be empty. `_t` is presumably a key passed in the request to the script serving it. And that's all

Answer (score -2):

There is no special meaning to the `_t` - it's just the name of the `input`s in the HTML.  Compare the HTML form that's submitted to your PHP with the processing code: if the code is reasonably correct, then you'll see references in PHP to each of the `input`s in HTML.

While coming from HTML is most likely, it's also possible that this element in the array is just being set on its own in PHP with `$_GET['_t'] = "some value";`

Comment: Doesn't actually have to be in the HTML, could be a code for tracking referrals or something (added to links in emails, or whatever).

Comment: Ok, fair enough, although somewhat unlikely.